# include(C:\xampp\htdocs\website\db_connection\dbconnection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I know there have been similar questions before but I've tried everything suggested in those threads and nothing is working for me. I tried setting the path, changing the location of the files, making sure permisions are right for the files in windows and nothing. I am trying run a php file that includes code to open another php file so I can acquire a connection but everything I do throws the same errors:

Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\website\db_connection\dbconnection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\db_connection\index.php on line 11

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\website\db_connection\dbconnection.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\website\db_connection') in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\db_connection\index.php on line 11

```
 <?php set_include_path('C:\\xampp\htdocs\website\db_connection'); ?>
 <?php 

 include('C:\\xampp\htdocs\website\db_connection\\dbconnection.php'); 
 ?>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO website (id, filelocation)
    VALUES ('".$_POST["id"]."','".$_POST["filelocation"]."')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 }

?>
```

location of files C:\xampp\htdocs\website\db_connection (both files are in this folder)

Maybe someone can see where I'm going wrong any help is appreciated

Comment: check the paths and permissions

Comment: output `var_dump(file_exists('C:\\xampp\htdocs\website\db_connection\\dbconnection.php'), is_readable('C:\\xampp\htdocs\website\db_connection\\dbconnection.php'));`

Comment: I checked both the paths and the permissions they are correct I'm not at my computer right now but I'll upload the output when Im back at my computer

Comment: Ok so I ran the code and it says there is no file which I don't understand because its showing up on my computer and I triple checked the permissions and they are fine. I even tried allowing full access and nothing. https://imgur.com/a/Pnodv

Comment: Ok I got it working don't know what was wrong I just copied the path again and it worked so we can close this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it working don't know what was wrong I just copied the path and file name again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
include('dbconnection.php');
```

only if two files in same folder?

and i think that you do not need `set_include_path`

if `index.php` in `website` folder you can use

```
include('db_connection/dbconnection.php');
```

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try the second one didn't think about using that I tried the first code. I used the include path because in one answer someone said changing it to the folder the files were in made there's work.